# Can Squid automatically add ETag?

Tags: proxy, squid, etags

Can Squid automatically add ETag based on page content, for the client not to download the same page twice?

Comment: I'd hope not, given that `ETag` is an origin server header, not a proxy header.

Comment: @womble What do you have against the idea that a proxy should add  `ETag` based on a hash of the page/headers content?

Comment: Because it's not how ETags are specified to work, and hence assumptions baked into *every* other piece of software about how ETags are supposed to work will be invalidated.  It's a bit like asking what I have against the idea that everyone should drive on the same side of the road.

Comment: @womble I don't understand what _exactly_ my idea contradicts in the `ETag` specs. Please explain what exactly is wrong in automatically calculating `ETag` based on the page content and other headers.

Answer (score 1):

Since Squid is, as far as I know, standards compliant Squid can't add Etag's.

[RFC 2616 13.5.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616?spm=5176.doc32013.2.3.Aimyd7#section-13.5.2) states:

> A transparent proxy **MUST NOT modify** any of the following fields in a
> request or response, and it **MUST NOT add any** of these fields if not
> already present:

> - Content-Location
> - Content-MD5
> - **ETag**
> - Last-Modified

You can recompile Squid with the `--enable-http-violations` option to enable some additional features that  break standards, but even that won't do (out-of-the-box) what you want.

The additional features such as [`reply_header_access`](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/reply_header_access/), [`request_header_access`](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/request_header_access/) and [`reply_header_replace`](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/reply_header_replace/) resp.  [`request_header_replace`](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/request_header_replace/) will only provide a method to modify headers with static pre-defined string, not calculated dynamic ones.

Comment: This is not a transparent proxy. It is a reverse proxy

Comment: Comments on answers are not the right place to clarify the scope of your question.